# Creating if statements with floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, floating-point

I am trying to create a conversion program that automatically copies converted text to windows clipboard. I am trying to make it so that if the user inputs a number that is taken out to 2 decimal places or less it copies the converted results taken out to 3 places to the clipboard. If the user inputs a number that is taken out to 3 decimal places or more it copies the converted results to the clipboard taken out to 4 decimal places. When I run the code I get a ValueError but I cant figure out why. Here is the error I am getting

```
line 88, in con
  if float_number >= ("%.3f" % float_number):
ValueError: incomplete format
```

Heres the part of the code thats giving me trouble(and I put in comments to explain things that might look like they are missing for you guys/gals)

```
def con():
    While True:
        print("Return = Main Menu, Surface = RA Conversion")
        print(MM_break) #This is defined globally elsewhere
        number = (input())
        if number in('Return', 'return'):
            break
        elif number in('Surface', 'surface'):
            surf() #I have a def surf() elsewhere in the program
        elif number in('help', 'Help'):
            help() #I have a def for help() elsewhere
        elif number in('end', 'exit', 'quit')
            break
        else:
             try:
                 float(number)
             except ValueError:
                 print(sys_Error) #I have a global variable for sys_Error elsewhere
                 break
             else:
                 float_number = float(number)
             Convert = float_number/Inches
             Results_3 = ("%.3f" % Convert)#converts 3 decimals
             Results_4 = ("%.4f" % Convert)#converts to 4 decimals
             print(line_break)
                 print(" ")
             print('\t', Results_3)
             print('\t', Results_4)
             print(line_break)
             print(" ")
             if float_number >= ("%.3f%" % float_number):
                 r = Tk()
                 r.withdraw()
                 r.clipboard_clear()
                 r.clipboard_append(Results_4)#appends Results_4 to clipboard
             else:
                 r = Tk()
                 r.withdraw()
                 r.clipboard_clear()
                 r.clipboard_append(Results_3)
```

Comment: Please do give us the *full* traceback of the error and not ask us to guess where the error occurs.

Comment: You don't need to call `float(number)` twice. Simply move `float_number = float(number)` inside the `try`/`except ..:` and remove the `else:` suite altogether.

Comment: I can see where your code would throw a `TypeError`, not a `ValueError`. Is that what you see?

Comment: I just added the Error its giving me to the question

Comment: Your error does not match your source code, but even if you fixed that it'd give a TypeError.

Comment: Well thats the error that it gives me when I run the code and I cant figure out whats causing it.

Comment: No, that is the error you get when you run code that is *approximately* the same as the code you posted here. Are you running this inside IDLE? Then you need to reload the code, it appears to be running an older version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error indicates you have an error in the string template, you are missing a `%`:

```
if float_number >= (".3f" % float_number):
```

should be

```
if float_number >= ("%.3f" % float_number):
```

**Hovever**, now you are trying to compare a `float` value with a string:

```
if float_number >= ("%.3f" % float_number):
```

That will throw a `TypeError`:

```
>>> 0.123 >= '0.123'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: float() >= str()
```

Don't do that. Compare floats to floats, use [`round()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to create rounded values:

```
if float_number >= round(float_number, 3):
```

Comment: That worked to get rid of the error except now it strictly copies Results_4 to the clipboard no matter what the input is and I am trying to make it so if the user enters lets say .05 it will return .002 and be copied to the clipboard but if the user enters .005 it would return .0002 and copy this to the clipboard instead.

Comment: You need to think more carefully about your conditions here; perhaps you could compare `round(float_number, 3) >= 0.01` for example.

Comment: @ Martijn that kinda solved my problem but what if the user enters 3.01 then it would print out .119 and copy, but if the user entered 3.001 I would want it to print out  .1181 and copy to clipboard

Comment: basically however many places the number the user enters is taken out to, determines how many number of places the program copys to the clipboard (I dont really know how to explain it)

Comment: @Inhale.Py: How about you take the original string input by the user, split on the decimal point and measure? `len(number.split('.')[1].strip())`.

Comment: basically I need the If statement to say If the the number was input at 3 decimal places copy the converted number to the clipboard at 4 decimal places else copy the converted number to the clipboard ta 3 decimal placces

Comment: Im new to python and that piece of code your showing is something I have never seen before. Do you think you can use it in an example so I can get a better Idea of what it does?

Comment: Python has excellent documentation and an excellent interactive interpreter. Why don't you try out the individual components in the interpreter ([`len()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len), [`str.split()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), [`str.strip()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)).

Comment: but I think I get what your saying. your saying split the user input at the decimal place and measure the number of characters (numbers) input by the user, then compare that to a set set of characters and if the results are = to or > print Results_4 and else print Results_3 but how would I put that into code? And I must seriously thank you because I am learning a lot of new things because of you.

Comment: Store the result of `len(number.split('.')[1].strip())` in a variable (`decimals_count` perhaps), then compare *that* number (an integer) to how many decimal places you expect. `if decimals_count <= 3:` is `True` if the user entered 3 or fewer decimals.

Comment: Thank you Martijn Pierters, I'll edit my code and post it in an answer. You were a great help to me today and I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have another question kinda within this question. when using len(number.split('.')[1].strip()) When the user inputs 1 the program crashes do to an IndexError: list index out of range how can I fix that?

Comment: @Inhale.Py: Use something like `try: decimals_count = len(number.split('.')[1].strip())`, `except IndexError: decimals_count = 0`; exception handling is the easiest way to handle that situation.

Comment: Thanks Ill give that a try and see what happens